# how to reroute http request in Roku Player for removing the headers?

Tags: http, routes, m3u8, roku

I  am trying to pass Headers with the HLS stream. Below is the sample Stream.

https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8?Params=1

But, It takes in both m3u8 and ts. I only need to pass this in m3u8. I need to reroute the request when calling the ts file.

Does anyone know How to Possible with Roku?.

Comment: Question is little bit unclear to me. What do you mean by reroute here?